# How to compile .ui file to python using pyside6-uic but with the snake_case and true_property activated

Tags: qt-designer, pyside6

The new version of Qt for Python (PySide6) allows to use a new feature named true_property, this feature you can easily use when you build your UI manually from scratch, but If you are using Qt Designer and you want to convert .ui files to python using pyside6-uic the python code is generated without taking in count that feature. So I want to know if there is a flag option or a command to tell pyside6-uic to use the true_property.

Comment: I don't think it can currently be done, I recommend you report it as a bug.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am going to do it, thank you.